# Setting custom paper size with KOMA Script / pdflatex

Tags: koma-script, paper-size

I try to set a document with some custom paper dimensions (lets say 24cm height and 17cm width), the beginning of the file looks like so:

```
\documentclass[liststotoc,bibtotoc,headsepline]{scrreprt}%draft

\input{xx_common_include}

\begin{document}
```

Where xx_common_include looks like this (extract)...

```
%------------------------------------
% KOMA Stuff
%------------------------------------

% General KOMAoptions

\KOMAoptions
  {
    fontsize=11pt,
    paper=a4,
    pagesize=pdftex
    %cleardoublepage=plain,
  }

% Headers

\usepackage{scrpage2} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\thepage}
\automark[section]{chapter}
```

Now, obviously the line "paper=a4" should look different in order to get the document to match the required size. How do I achieve that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7):

you can do that like this

```
paper=5cm:3cm,
DIV=calc,
```

Comment: With this I'm able to make the page smaller but the text I already have doesn't centre. So the text gets cut off on the right and at the bottom. Any tips how I can fix this problem?

Comment: @menetl of corse you need to change others dimensions text margins ... you can do this with 
DIV=calc. I edit my answer.

Comment: @touhami And what should I do if I need a A1 paper sheet and inside the document, how can I adjust the margins for can use the most of the paper surface?

Comment: please try `\KOMAoptions{paper=a1, DIV=15}` or `\KOMAoptions{paper=a1}\areaset{.95\paperwidth}{.95\paperheight}`