# Setting KOMA-Script document in half legal paper

Tags: koma-script, paper-size, typearea

I need to resize a letter sized document into a page with a half legal paper size. I'm using KOMA-Script class `scrbook`, but I can't get it using `typarea`. Surelly I'm doing something wrong. I [read this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228118/setting-custom-paper-size-with-koma-script-pdflatex) before ask. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[headings=big,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[headinclude=false,footinclude=false,paper=legal,landscape,paper=35.6cm:21.6in,DIV=10]{typearea}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\subject{Thesis}
\title{Vertical borderline}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

What I need is a document with a half legal sheet page, for print two pages over a legal sized sheet of paper. Suggestions?

Comment: `paper=7cm:9cm` should do\*. Use it after `bibliography=totoc`. \* Substitute real dimensions. EDIT: You gotta move all the options from `typearea`  to the options of documentclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following MWE you get an document with landscape, half legal size with KOMA-Script class `scrbook` based on your given code.  See the important code changings marked with `<========`.

```
\documentclass[%
  headings=big,
  bibliography=totoc,
  headinclude=false, % <================================================
  footinclude=false, % <================================================
% paper=21.6cm:35.6cm, % Legal   8 1⁄2 × 14 inch    216 × 356 mm
  paper=10.8cm:17.8cm, % legal/2 landscape  paper=width:heigth <========
  paper=landscape, % <==================================================
  DIV=10           % <==================================================
]{scrbook}

%\areaset{10cm}{17cm} % {width}{height} <==================== without DIV
\usepackage{showframe} % <=========================== to show typing area

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\subject{Thesis}
\title{Vertical borderline}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

Text text text text text % <================================ for 2nd page

\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image]

Please see that the **current** version of KOMA-Script uses `paper=width:height` **instead** in earlier versions `paper=height:width`.  Please see my comments in the given MWE.